# RAML file is throwing invalid Json schema response in Anypoint Studio

Tags: json, mule, jsonschema, anypoint-studio, raml

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.2 with Mule 3.8.1 and I have added a raml and JSON schema which shows no errors in api-workbench but show Json schema invalid errors in Anypoint Studio.

I have found that if I remove the required field from all of my Json schemas linked to the raml (i.e. raml, traits and types) then everything works. Is there a way to fix this?

The required syntax I am using is:

```
"required": [
    "Organisation",
    "Address"
  ],
```

> **Updated**

and I am also seeing a `org.mule.common.metadata.parser.json.SchemaException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:` where the $ref cannot be resolved when using the JSON schema to create a metadata type to use in Dataweave:

```
{
    "id": "http://localhost:8000/schemas/products.json#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Products",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Products": {
            "$ref": "common/text.json"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it only supports v3 schema. Try using put "required": "true" in each field (which is v3 schema format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same, so it is definitely supported in Studio. Without seeing your entire JSON schema file I have to guess at the cause, and my assumption is that you either don't specify a JSON schema version or you are specifying the wrong one (should be at least v4, not v3 for this to work). The following works for me:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Organisation": { "type": "string" },
    "Address": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "Organisation", "Address" ]
}
```

Comment: I've found that when I follow Pedro's advice that it all issues are resolved and if I revert back to using the required array then the errors return so look like its only compatible at the moment with v3.  Is there something I need to do to more it to the latest version?

Comment: Did you add "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema", to your json schema as Brad suggested ?

Comment: Yeah, as per Pedro's comment and my answer you need to specify schema version 4. As I originally said, this definitely works in studio for the projects I'm working on.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding $schema has been able to resolve the majority of the errors I'm seeing.  I do have one more where when I use a schema that uses $ref to create a metadata type, it throws an error but it works when I remove the reference and add the code from the file directly.  Do you know what could be causing that to happen?  I have updated the code above with an example schema that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the new addition - $ref - we also use this, and it seems to be resolved correctly by APIKit (i.e. messages are correctly validated) however I don't use these schemas to create Dataweave metadata so I cannot guarantee that it will behave the same (I would hope it uses the same parser, but cannot say for sure).

Common.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "definitions": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "description": "Basic RegEx for an email address",
            "type": ["string","null"],
            "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9'._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
        }
    }   
}
```

Sample.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "email": {
            "$ref": "common.json#/definitions/emailAddress"
        }
    }
}
```